# proving that the bn term of the fourier series of f is finite if f is odd

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, fourier-series

let $L>0$ and $f:[0, L] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and odd function that satisfies $f(0)=0=f(L)$. also, $f^{\prime}$ is smooth and continously integrable in $[0, L]$. Also remember that:
$$
b_n=\frac{2}{L} \int_0^L f(x) \sin \left(\frac{n \pi x}{L}\right) d x, n \geq 1 .
$$

its the bn term of its fourier series

show that: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|b_n\right|<+\infty$.

my attempt:

so, since f is odd we know that $a_n$ and $a_0$ are equal to zero, and so its fourier series is simply:

$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_{n}\sin\left(\dfrac{nx\pi}{L}\right)$

and by parsavel we have:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (b_n)^2 = \frac{2}{L} \int_0^L |f(x)|^2 \, dx$

so i thought, hey, maybe we can find that $(bn)^2$ with the fourier series (term by term), so we have:

$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_{n}\sin\left(\dfrac{nx\pi}{L}\right)$

and since f is smooth we can do its derivative as follows:

$f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n\pi}{L} b_n \cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)$

and using the fact that ab is less or equal than (a^2 + b^2)/2:

$2f'(x) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |b_n|^2 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{n\pi}{L}\right)^2 \cos^2\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)$

ok, so up to here i am a bit stuck, I though that since |bn|^2 is still true I can bound it from either the left or right and that in conclusion will give me that $b_n$ is bounded and so finite, but then again I am a bit stuck. I am on the right track?

Comment: since the Fourier coefficients of the derivative are $\sim nb_n$ it follows that $\sum n^2|b_n|^2< \infty$ by Parseval so applying Cauchy to $b_n=(nb_n)\times (1/n)$ gives you the convergence of $\sum |b_n|$

Comment: Suggestion: Integrate by parts twice.

Comment: thanks so much, now I could complete my proof. It was easier than I thought it will be!